# Magento StoreView specific .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, magento, ip

I'm using a second domain for my second storeview in Magento.

I want to block this second domain for some countries, and I have already find an solution:

http://www.ip2location.com/blockvisitorsbycountry.aspx

The solution is working great but in my case I have an problem, because I need this solution only for one storeview, not for both.

How can I control that and what do I need to add in the .htaccess file
to block some countries only for the second storeview?

Thank You